# Can't make balls bounce back

Tags: javascript

I can't make the balls move in the opposite direction. Here is my code:

```
var xPositions = [random(0,400),random(0,400),random(0,400),random(0,400),random(0,400),random(0,400),random(0,400),random(0,400),random(0,400),random(0,400)];
var yPositions = [random(0,400),random(0,400),random(0,400),random(0,400),random(0,400),random(0,400),random(0,400),random(0,400),random(0,400),random(0,400)];

draw = function() {
    background(250,250, 250);
var velocidad=5;
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        fill(230, 156, 156);
        ellipse(xPositions[i], yPositions[i], 10, 10);
   var d=1;
   if(yPositions[i]>=400){
     d= -1;
} else if(yPositions[i]<=0){
     d = 1;
}
       yPositions[i] = yPositions[i] + velocidad*d ;
    }

};
```

Comment: You need to edit your question to include what specifically is not working and the shortest code to be able to reproduce the problem.  As it stands I could not copy this code to a jsfiddle or something similar and see the problem.  Even if I could guess how to fix your problem, this question needs to be written so it can help future visitors.  See [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to make an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You are setting d=1 in every iteration before you check the bounds.
Move

```
var d=1
```

out of the function or out of the loop.

Comment: This won't change anything, since `d` is hoisted anyways, and `d` always has a value according to the `if / else if` statements

Comment: @aduch You are right, var is always at function scope, but is the assignment d=1 also evaluated only once?

Comment: Even more importantly, d needs to be a property of each sprite. Otherwise they'll always just hover in the same place when they hit the bounds. Your suggestion would make every ball inherit the direction of the latest ball in the loop. They'd still just kinda hover though.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're not saving the direction `d` each ball is traveling. In your code, once a ball reaches the edge, it will go in the opposite direction. Until it's inside the bounds again, in that loop it'll change direction again.

Which leads to the main problem with your code, having two separate arrays of `x` and `y` coordinates instead of one array of `ball` objects. Something like

```
function Ball() {
  this.x = random(0,400);
  this.y = random(0,400);
  this.direction = 1; // Or if you want to randomize: random(0,99)<50 ? -1 : 1;
  this.velocity = 5; // Or if you want to randomize: random(1, 5)
}

Ball.prototype = {
  draw:function() {
    fill(230, 156, 156);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, 10, 10);
  },
  update:function() {
    var newposition = this.y+this.direction*this.velocity;
    if (newposition < 0 || newposition > 400) {
      this.direction*=-1; // If outside of bounds, reverse position
    }
    this.y = this.y+this.direction*this.velocity;
  }
};
```

Then you initiate your balls as such

```
var balls = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){
  balls.push(new Ball());
}
```

And in your main loop you just need to call `balls[i].update()` and  `balls[i].draw()`.

```
draw = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    balls[i].update();
    balls[i].draw();
  }
};
```

There are still lots of things to be improved, but here's the gist of OOP to get you started.